# Greasemonkey script to make Fixed Positioned Elements Static

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, greasemonkey

I find elements on a web page that have been positioned fixed to be in my way frequently. I'd like to find a way to disable `position: fixed` CSS rules in any web site that I visit.

I wrote a userscript (Firefox, Greasemonkey) that scans every node in the document and figures out if it has a computed style position fixed, then overrides that to be static.

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

This is the script I wrote, I've narrowed it to just divs for now:

```
Array.forEach(
    document.querySelectorAll("div")
    ,function(el) {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(el).position === 'fixed') {
            el.style.position = 'static';
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Purely just wondering why you want to do this? Wouldn't it break some styling that "relies" on fixed positioning? I know it's unrelated to the question, I'm just wondering

Comment: @Ian Maybe he's making a screenshot plugin?

Comment: I've gotten used to zooming a page on my desktop until the main content fills the window, like viewing a page on my cell phone. Perhaps I'm old. Fixed position elements frequently overlay the content. I think that fixed elements are generally divorced from page content, so I don't expect too much breakage.

Comment: for(var a=document.querySelectorAll("*"),i=0,e;e=a[i];i++)"fixed"==getComputedStyle(e).position&&(e.style.position="static") [-Jeremy Ashkenas](https://twitter.com/jashkenas/status/534741312525070337)

Comment: The previous comment seems to contain zero-width spaces, for some reason, so it's not copy-pastable (though it does work).

Comment: They seem to be inserted by stackoverflow as a means of preventing overflowing lines, since creating a fresh comment with the correct content (with no hidden spaces) still led to the result containing the hidden spaces. Using code tags did not help.

Comment: Cross-referencing similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664285/how-do-i-disable-positionfixed-in-web-pages https://superuser.com/a/902531/580566

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Greasemonkey script works, it is probably the most cost effective way to eliminate fixed-positioned styling.

Some alternatives that require much more effort but will use less CPU/memory per page:

1. Write [***an Add-on***](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) that:

   1. Deletes CSS style rules as they are loaded.  (Greasemonkey cannot always do this because of cross-domain issues.)
   2. Uses [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) to intercept javascript attempts to set `position: fixed`.
2. Fork and compile your own version of Firefox that ignores `position: fixed`. You'd probably want this controlled by both a "blacklist" and a "whitelist".