# How do I disable position:fixed in web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, bookmarklet

This website:

http://nautil.us/

has a really annoying header that is always on screen and won't scroll away.

If I right-click on it and 'inspect element' in firefox, then I find that the css contains "position: fixed;", and if I untick this, the header behaves, and scrolls away as God intended headers to do.

Is there some way to get firefox to do this automatically, i.e. remove all position: fixed lines from all pages before rendering them?

edit-------

After a bit of thought, what I want is a bookmarklet that will kill off this sort of thing.

So how to turn SciMonster's promising-looking:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('*'); // get all elements
for (var i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.position == 'fixed') {
        x[i].style.position = 'static';
    }
}
```

into

```
javascript:???
```

suitable for going in the location field of a firefox bookmark?

With the win condition that if you go to http://nautil.us, and click the bookmarklet button, the floating header stops floating and scrolls away, as if you had deleted `position: fixed;` in the element inspector.

Comment: You could probably make your own FF plugin as I doubt one exists. But you'd probably break a lot of stuff.

Comment: (Feel free to add the [javascript] and/or [userscript] tags, based on my answer.)

Comment: You could do a bookmarklet. The minute you navigate to the site you could click a button in the browser window and it would disappear. [WIKI LINK HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). Give me a mo to read up about it and I'll have a look again.

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: You will break a lot of layouts like that.  You'll probably make things harder than they are now.

Comment: Billy, firefox. I tried putting Scimonster's code into a bookmarklet but no joy so far. Do let me know if you solve it!

Comment: make yourself a GreaseMonkey script dude. google it.

Comment: fair, but if it doesn't work as a bookmarklet why would it work as a Greasemonkey script? Nevertheless, on the mother...

Comment: ok, can't make it work as a greasemonkey script either...

Comment: The problem with scimonster's otherwise great solution is that `element.style` only returns styles defined inline, not those specified in external css files, etc. Googling and looking at similar questions suggested that using `getComputedStyle(element)` solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is great:

https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/kill-sticky-headers/

A sticky header is a sure sign of stuff you don't want on your screen, and this just destroys them!

Could probably modify it to change them from fixed to static, but I haven't found a case where I actually want to.

Answer (score 4):

These two questions on
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696100/greasemonkey-script-to-make-fixed-positioned-elements-static)
and
[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/148536/how-can-i-disable-the-css-positionfixed-side-bar-on-slashdot)
are very similar.

Arguably, the easiest solution (suggested in the [answers on
superuser](https://superuser.com/a/902531/580566)) is to install [this
greasemonkey
script](https://gist.github.com/vbuaraujo/bddb3b93a0b2b7e28e1b). It has
the advantage that it tries to be clever by looping only over relevent
html elements and attempting to recognise pseudo-pop-up windows, and not
unfixing those. It will automatically run on all loaded webpages unless
you edit the `@include` header line. (I have not actually tested it.)

If you want a bookmarklet, then this should do the job (tested
on nautil.us):

```
javascript:(function(){x=document.querySelectorAll('*');for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){if(getComputedStyle(x[i]).position=="fixed"){x[i].style.position="absolute";}}}())
```

As a bonus, considering that css `position: sticky` headers are now
also popping up their ugly heads, you can get rid of both them and "fixed"
elements:

```
javascript:(function(){x=document.querySelectorAll('*');for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){elementStyle=getComputedStyle(x[i]);if(elementStyle.position=="fixed"||elementStyle.position=="sticky"){x[i].style.position="absolute";}}}())
```

Not compressed:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    elementStyle = getComputedStyle(x[i]);
    if(elementStyle.position=="fixed" || elementStyle.position=="sticky") {
        x[i].style.position="absolute";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080590/3187556) which tells how to find elements with a specific CSS property (using jQuery):

```
var x = $('.myselector').filter(function () { 
    return this.style.position == 'fixed' 
});
```

If we then use that returned set, we can reset the positions to static:

```
var x = $('*').filter(function () { 
    return this.style.position == 'fixed' 
}).css('position', 'static');
```

Just place this in a userscript (with jQuery included) and you're all set!

---

And a non-jQuery solution...

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('*'); // get all elements
for (var i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.position == 'fixed') {
        x[i].style.position = 'static';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scimonster!. If I make a bookmarklet saying "javascript:alert(document.links[0].href)" then that works, but if I make one saying "javascript:var x=document.querySelectorAll('*'); for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){if(x[i].style.position=='fixed'){x[i].style.position='static';}};" then it doesn't. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Scimonster. I used your jQuery solution, but altered it to query for the header tag (and imported jQuery):

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

$("header").css('position', 'absolute');
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update again again*

A Vanilla JS solution:

```
/* find the topbar by coordinate */
var topbar
var el = document.elementFromPoint(document.documentElement.clientWidth - 200, 20)
while (el) {
    if (getComputedStyle(el).position == 'fixed') topbar = el
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el == document.body) break
}
if (topbar == undefined) return

/* disable position:fixed */
// topbar.style.position = 'absolute'
// ↑ this line doesn't work well, because sometime offsetParent is not <body>
// ↓ workaround
var paint = function (enforce) {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
    var threshold = 200
    if (!enforce && scrollTop > threshold * 3) return
    var offset = scrollTop / threshold
    if (offset > 1.2) offset = 1.2
    topbar.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + offset * 100 + '%)'
}
paint(true) // initialize
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => paint())

/* when use JS to frequently change CSS value, disable CSS transition to avoid weird delay */
// topbar.style.transition = 'transform 0s'
// ↑ this line doesn't work because of compatibility
// ↓ workaround
topbar.classList.add('remove-topbar')
var style = document.createElement('style')
style.innerHTML = '.remove-topbar{transition:transform 0s !important}'
document.head.appendChild(style)
```

Userscript:
https://gist.github.com/zcyzcy88/909b77054b88fd69e8a0834b84e7a68b